# Instead of replacing duplicate file format it to have a _1_ in files name

Tags: python-3.x

I need to change my script so instead of replacing files if they got the same name they would add *1*, *2* etc etc.
example:
ARR_NIS_1570520881 will be renamed to ARR_AUD_1570520881
but if I was to run my script and there's already an ARR_AUD_1570520881 it would replace the old file with the new.
what I want is for the old ARR_AUD_1570520881 to become ARR_AUD_1_1570520881
any help would be appreciated

```
import os

counter = 0
path ="xxxxxx" #path to folder containing csv files

starting_as = ("ARR", "GTO", "POD", "PDI", "FIN")
replace = 'AUD'
new_name = "NIS"

for file in os.listdir(path):
    if file.startswith(starting_as):
     if file.find(replace) > 0:
      counter = counter + 1
      os.rename(os.path.join(path, file), os.path.join(path, file.replace(replace ,new_name)))

files = []
for file in os.listdir(path):
    if file.startswith(starting_as):
          if file.find(replace) > 0:
                counter = counter + 1
                newFileName = file.replace(replace ,new_name)
                file = newFileName
                files.append((file, newFileName))
print("no files found")
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
filename = 'ARR_AUD_1570520881'
new_filename = filename
i = 1
while new_filename in os.listdir():
    new_filename = filename.split('_')
    new_filename.insert(-2,str(i))
    new_filename = '_'.join(new_filename)
    i += 1
```

EDIT: realised I made a mistake yesterday, corrected the code

Comment: Sort of, just "new_filename"  would have to go through all 1500 odd files, also having a hard time figuring out how I would go about implementing this into my script as I'm getting "[WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists:" when I try.

Comment: this should not be that problematic since you don't open/close all these files but just iterate through a list of strings. I corrected my code, maybe it works now.